# ffplay - Is there a way to display a video and spectrogram in the same output?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio

I'm trying to analyze a spectrogram while simultaneously checking the video, without having to switch between them.  Something like this, but with the video combined in the same output:

[image]

The idea is to be able to scrub through both video and the spectrogram so that they're synced.  Most editing software only lets me see the waveforms.  The command I used for that is as follows:

```
ffplay -f lavfi 'amovie=/Users/hdl/Desktop/HDLS3K.mp4, asplit [a][out1];
[a] showspectrum=size=1280x512:mode=separate:slide=scroll [out0]'
```

Comment: Depending on what your user case is, you may want to have a look at [QCTools](https://github.com/bavc/qctools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffplay -f lavfi 'amovie=/Users/hdl/Desktop/HDLS3K.mp4:s=dv+da[v][a];[a]asplit[asp][out1];
   [asp]showspectrum=size=1280x512:mode=separate:slide=scroll[spect];
   [v]scale=640:-1[v];[v][spect]vstack[out0]'
```

`amovie` usually selects only one (audio) stream. `dv+da` gets it to extract the best video and the best audio stream. The video output is scaled so that the vstack works.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but I did have to make a little change.  Apparently it wants the spectrum size and scale set to the same value, else it spits an error.  I set them both to 640 and that did it.

Comment: With this it seems like the spectrum visualization has a bit of a delay on it.  Any tips for improving that?